# How to get the CSS class of a span using Selenium Web Driver in Java

Tags: java, automation, selenium-webdriver

I have a span element like this

```
<span id="yui-gen56" class="ir i-doc" style="background-color: transparent;"></span>
```

Now I want to retrieve the class attribute value so that it should return me `ir i-doc` for verification. Any idea how can I get this attribute value for further verification.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like below where driver is object of WebDriver -

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id("yui-gen56"));
webElement.getAttribute("class");
```

Comment: Simple and ultimate working solution, thanks Bhushan!!

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
WebElement cssValue = driver.findelement(By.cssSelector("[id='yui-gen56'][class='ir i-doc']"));
String Value = divElement.getText();
System.out.println(Value);
```

It helped me in finding value of css class..